How to get all routes to build a dynamic navigation menu using flutter_modular
I am making an application with different modules managing it with flutter_modular but I cannot access in some dynamic way the routes of the different modules.
class MainModule extends Module {
  final List<ModuleRoute> _moduleRoutes = [
    ModuleRoute('/inicio/', module: InicioModule()),
    ModuleRoute('/empleados/', module: EmpleadosModule()),
    ModuleRoute('/inventario/', module: InventarioModule()),
  ];

  List<ModuleRoute> get moduleRoutes => _moduleRoutes;

  @override
  void binds(i) {
  }

  @override
  void routes(r) {
  
    r.child('/',
        child: (context) => const MainPage(),
        children: _moduleRoutes,
        transition: TransitionType.fadeIn);
  }
}```
The objective is to obtain all the child routes that are used inside the different modules to be able to dynamically generate the navigation menu.


I have tried to access the instances of the modules but always find the values ​​of the empty routes although the application is working.
It is the first time I make a post, if there is missing information or if someone could help me I would appreciate it very much. Thank you!
